# How to update gamehud in a CCSprite or CCNode, Cocos2d

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

I have a `Gamehud` where I want to display an object's name. There are lots of objects/sprites in main scene what I am trying to do is to display selected(on touch) objects' name on `Gamehud`.

Problem is if I alloc `Gamehud` in `CCsprite` class it creates new instance and does not update current `Gamehud`. If I use something like `GameHUD *gamehud=  (GameHUD *)[self.parent getChildByTag:99];` nothing happens I cannot send the object to GameHud class.

So what would be the correct way to update game hud in a `ccsprite or ccnode`class?

Main Scene;

```
-(id) init
{
    if ((self = [super init]))
    {            
        gameHud = [GameHUD gamehud];
        [self addChild:gameHud z:2 tag:99];
    }
}
```

My GameHud

```
+(id) gamehud
{
    return [[self alloc] init];
}

-(id) init
{
    if ((self = [super init]))
    {
        //bunch of labels
    }
}


-(void)showName: :(Object *)obj
{
    NSLog(@"Object name is %@", obj.name);
    [_labelSpeed setString:obj.name];
}
```

In Object Class:CCSprite

```
-(void) onTouch
{
    //obj is the object with name property that I want to use
    GameHUD *gamehud=  (GameHUD *)[self.parent getChildByTag:99]; // does not send the obj to gamehud and showName is not called
    //GameHud *gamehud= [GameHud alloc] init]; // this displays nslog but doesnt update _label
    [gamehud showName:obj];
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could create a delegate method on that CCSprite object. that get's fire when it was selected. Then in your main scene get the objects name and call `[gameHud showName:objectName]`

Comment: You definitely don't want to set the hud from inside the object though.

Comment: Another option is to check which subviews are being touched in the mainScene, then do it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to create a singleton or something like a semi singleton. Just add new nsobject class name "SingletonGameHud" to your app

SingletonGameHud.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "GameHUD.h"

//create singleton class to use gamehud in movingobject class
@interface SingletonGameHud : NSObject
{
    GameHUD *gamingHud;

}

@property(nonatomic,strong) GameHUD *gamingHud;

+(SingletonGameHud *)sharedInstance;


@end
```

SingletonGameHud.m

```
#import "SingletonGameHud.h"
#import "GameHUD.h"

@implementation SingletonGameHud

@synthesize gamingHud=_gamingHud;


+ (SingletonGameHud *)sharedInstance
{
    static SingletonGameHud *sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[SingletonGameHud alloc] init];
        // Do any other initialisation stuff here
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}

- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _gamingHud = [GameHUD hud];

    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

in your game scene call

```
SingletonGameHud *sharedInstance= [SingletonGameHud sharedInstance];
hud = sharedInstance.gamingHud;
[self addChild:hud z:2 tag:99];
```

in your on touch method call

```
-(void) onTouch
{
    SingletonGameHud *sharedInstance= [SingletonGameHud sharedInstance];
    [sharedInstance.gamingHud showName:obj];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all use a singlton or you will create a new GameHub everytime you call `+(id) gamehud`. i think this could be your problem: you add one GameHUD to the scene and call showName: of another object of GameHUD. Another problem is your `-(id)init` - you dont return `self`! so you never get your GameHUD

```
static GameHUD *sharedInstance = nil;
+(id) gamehud {
    if( !sharedInstance ) {
        sharedInstance = [[GameHUD alloc] init]
    }
    return sharedInstance;
}

-(id) init {
    self = [super init];
    if ( self ) {
       //bunch of labels

       sharedInstance = self; 
    }
    return self; //i dont see this in your code!
}
```

from now you can access your hud from every point you want and you dont need to handle with tags. Be careful, its not the best way to create a Singleton (ask google). Dont call ..alloc] init] use only `[GameHUD gamehud];`

```
-(void) onTouch {
    [[GameHUD gamehud] showName:obj];
}
```

Good Luck!

Comment: `return self;` is just a copy paste error I have it in my code. Thanks for the answer